# Инструмент для layout preview из xml разметки Android

Tags: android, android-layout, ide, preview

Cтолкнулся с проблемой - совсем не могу найти инструмента для layout preview из xml разметки. Даже грубо напоминающего встроенный в IDE вариант.
Подскажите кто знает о подобных инструментах. Может это будет онлайн сервис, главное - это полная самостоятельность от любой IDE.
Необходимо только видеть preview (не обязательно редактировать) и желательно, чтобы было чтение из файла.
[image: layout preview из Android Studio]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не смотря на кажущуюся простоту задачи, для отображения визуального вида разметки на основе xml-файла требуется, как минимум, Android SDK, а так же исходники классов библиотек и собственных классов проекта, если они будут отображаться на экране (кастомные View) и компилятор, так как вид генерируется из кода view-классов, которые присутствуют в разметке.

В связи со всем этим визуальный просмотрщик разметки отдельно от IDE и всего проекта в целом несколько бессмысленнен и вряд ли такой существует.